# Why are there two ways of the conjugation of some verbs, e.g., "provveduto" and "provvisto"?

Tags: verbs, word-choice, etymology

Why are there two ways of the conjugation of some verbs? For example "provvedere" shown in the dictionary. Is the red one more commonly used?

[image]

Comment: The red colour seems to me to indicate that the conjugation form is irregular.

Comment: It's just that some tenses of some specific Italian verbs admit two different forms ([an example](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/premere)). For the specific case of "provvisto" and "provveduto", [they usually have different usages](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/provveduto/). I would recommend to check this kind of things on a dictionary.

Comment: That said, your question is not completely clear to me. What exactly are you expecting to see in an answer?

Comment: About what I heard from my teacher in middle school, verbs with multiple conjugation in *past participle* have the one that ends with `one vocal` + `to` that is the older version while the other is newer. Probably, the oldest one will disappear in the future use

Comment: The verb *provvedere* is a composite of *pro* and *vedere*. The conjugation of *vedere* has the same peculiarities. However *veggo*, *veggono* and *vidente* are antiquated and no longer common; *veduto* and *visto* alternate. On the other hand *provvisto* is commonly used only as an adjective and the past tenses are formed with *provveduto*.

Comment: @Charo - I think the OP is asking “why” a verb, in this case provvedere, has two different forms, for instance, in the past participle. It is an interesting  question which is not easy to answer.

Comment: So, it's a question about etymology, @Hachi? Or they are simply trying to understand the contents of the source of the image in the question?

Comment: Well, the question clearly asks “why” so I guess it is an etymological issue.

Comment: It may be that way, @Hachi, but it's not completely clear to me: this is the reason of my previous comment.

Comment: As egreg correctly notes some of those forms are no longer common (like provveggo for instance), but the question still remains.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Sorry for not expressing my question clearly. I got curious about etymology things when I was looking it up in the dictionary. I was wondering if there might be some explanations about that. Is there a kind of verbs more likely to have two forms of participles? Perhaps, I'm just guessing, the older version may follow some regulations of pronunciation and the newer version is more and more commonly used simply because it's easier to remember the regular ones?

Comment: @smartsheep What diccionary is your screenshot from? I like it and I'd like to use it, too :)

Comment: In Spanish it often happened that some words were adopted from Latin historically twice. The word changed differently upon each "import". Eg. *key*: LAT - *clavis*, SPA - *llave* (for unlocking door), *clave* (password). Could this also be the case in Italian, that the verb in some of its form was kind of "double-imported" from Latin and distorted differently upon each import?

Comment: Thank you very much, Honza. It's Eudic. Unfortunately, there's only the Chinese version of the dictionary I guess. (So sorry for the mistake about your name last time!)